# how to execute second loop iteration after ajax done

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, delay, execution

how to delay for loop until function "some_multi_ajax_function()" change global variable (exe_counter will be 0) ?

```
for (i = 0; i < some_data_list.length; i++) {
    exe_counter=1;
     if(i>0 && exe_counter != 0){
            delay{
                // delay for loop until some_multi_ajax_function() set exe_counter = 0
                // do not execute second iteration
            }
      }else{
            data = some_data_list[i];
           // Many ajax posts will be executed here. In the end exe_counter will be set to 0;
           some_multi_ajax_function(data);
      }
}

function some_multi_ajax_function(data){
    $.ajax({
            ...
      }.done(function(d) {
           // here it could be used another ajax function 
           exe_counter = 0;
      });
}
```

Comment: What your script is supposed to do exactly?

Comment: search ads by coordinates, coordinated gets from google api. And it can serach 10 times

Answer (score 3):

You take the problem with a wrong solution.

If you want to wait an Ajax action you have to use callback only.

Then recursively you should do :

```
function some_multi_ajax_function(data, i) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    }.done(function(d) {
         if (i < data.length) {
             some_multi_ajax_function(data, i + 1);
         } else {
             // Do something in the end
         }
    });
}

some_multi_ajax_function(some_data_list, 0);
```

Comment: I can't do it, because some_multi_ajax_function() calls another Ajax function couple times

Comment: So just make your calls synchronous by adding this option async: false